# ace.js selection of word by user does not work

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using ace.js, but I have a strange problem, after changing the content of the editor,
selection of words (or line) by user (using mouse) does not work.

Here a video where I show the problem (I hope it's ok):
http://videobam.com/zxDaO

Anyone has idea about the reason of this issue?

EDIT:
Post a little of code to clear the situation:

```
function init(editor_, wsocket, curProj, projManager) {
    ws = wsocket;
    drawer = require("../../lib/statemachine/stateMachine");
    currentProject = curProj;
    editor = editor_;
    pm = projManager;  
    writer = new WriterOnContent(editor_);
     }

function WriterOnContent( editor) {   
    this.defaultStateName = "  StateName: TYPE";    this.delimitator = ',' ;    this.editor = editor; //*******
    this.userIsModifying = 0;
     }
```

If I comment the line in WriterOnContent : this.editor = editor;  I have not the problem, but I really don't understand why.

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle example of your problem?

Comment: I'd like to, but it's a big project and it's difficult to isolate the code that produces the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is something in your code
put a breakpoint with console.trace() at [selection.js#L80](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/71ceca46015e264d62a1eb88faa580a8481ad558/lib/ace/selection.js#L80) and [selection.js#L80](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/71ceca46015e264d62a1eb88faa580a8481ad558/lib/ace/selection.js#L88)
to see what modifies ace selection.